# Flutter: How to have one tap handler for two widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've got an `IconButton` and `Text` as the children of a `Row` widget. Currently when user taps on the calendar icon, its `onPressed` is handled and a calendar is shown to pick a date. However I want to extend the tapping area and allow the calendar to open even when user taps on the `Text` widget. What's the best way to achieve this purpose?

Please note that there are more children in this `Row`. I only want to handle the tap on these two children.

[image]

Comment: inkwell makes all its child widgets able to press, so all you need to do is defining the row as a inkwell child or put the row in a container and put container in an inkwell read more about it https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html

Answer (score 2):

`InkWell` might do the trick for you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DoubleTapPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: InkWell(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
              Text('2021 Jan 23')
            ],
          ),
          onTap: () => print('Calendar or Date tapped'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In response to the edit:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DoubleTapPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text('Outside the well'),
            InkWell(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  Text('2021 Jan 23')
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () => print('Calendar or Date tapped'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see the updated question. There are more children in the row.

Comment: @BFaley The InkWell gives a visible splash effect, so its possible to see what has been tapped.  Row items outside the InkWell will remain static.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole `Row` in `GestureDetector` as following

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // what your want here
  }
  child: Row(
    // ...
  ),
),
```